# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" after instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my code:

```
- (IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    DestinationViewController *destinationViewController = [[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Destination"] autorelease];
    destinationViewController.title = @"image property";
    destinationViewController.img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbnail"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationViewController animated:YES];

    [destinationViewController release];
}
```

The output is:

```
2012-07-20 10:43:29.976 jsonimage2[682:f803] 5 - fifth activity -http://i1184.photobucket.com/albums/z328/iElmoTutorials/CrazyEye.png
2012-07-20 10:43:31.878 jsonimage2[682:f803]  The button's image is <UIImage: 0x6aa16c0>.
2012-07-20 10:43:33.846 jsonimage2[682:f803] it works
2012-07-20 10:43:33.861 jsonimage2[682:f803] -[ViewController setImg:]:  unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68a8b80
```

Comment: First of all, it should be thubnail.extention for example thumbnamil.png. And where are you getting crash?

Comment: hey have you synthesized your "img object" in destinatioviewcontroller

Comment: Ya I synthesized "img object" in DestiantionViewController.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Answer (score 0):

From the doc, [`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontrollerwithide?language=objc) returns a `__kindof UIViewController *`.

Your code is attributing it to a `DestinationViewController *`, but actually it was returning `ViewController *` according to the crash log. So you probably forgot to set the class of `"Destination"` correctly in the Storyboard.

Answer (score -1):

The line that sets `destinationViewController.img` would trigger an implicit call to `setImg:`.

I can't see the definition of `DestinationViewController` but it apparently does not contain a definition of the `img` property.  You can either implement this by adding an apprpropriate `@property` for `img`, or by implementing the `setImg:` and `img` methods.

Answer (score -1):

you should forget @synthesize img right after @implementation DestinationViewController

Comment: I synthesize img variable in destinationViewController.

Comment: hmm;( maybe i need to see DestinationViewController header